# Java default value of instance variables of a class not initialized to zero for int

Tags: java, methods, tostring

This is an example I was working on from my java tutorial.
I have a Time1 class that does not have a constructor, and hence I was expecting it to be initialized with the default values to int, that is zero.

```
public class Time1 {
    private int hour; // expected to be initialised with zero
    private int minute; // expected to be initialised with zero
    private int second; // expected to be initialised with zero

    public void setTime(int hour, int minute, int second) {
        if (hour < 0 || hour >= 24 || minute < 0 || minute >= 60 || second < 0 || second >= 60) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("value out of range");
        }
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public String toUniversalString() {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s", ((hour == 0 || hour == 12) ? 12 : hour % 12), minute, second, (hour < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"));
    }
}
```

And now I have the main class

```
public class Time1test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Time1 thistime = new Time1();
        System.out.println(thistime);
        thistime.setTime(13, 22, 33);
        System.out.println(thistime);
    }
}
```

I was expecting `System.out.println(thistime);` before using the `setTime()` method to return 00:00:00 because I haven't used any methods to reformat it, however I am getting the output as 12:00:00 AM, that is equal  to calling `toString()` method. Why was this method being called by default when a new object is initialized, even without being called for?

Comment: Why were you expecting `00:00:00`? Did you expect Java to automatically call `toUniversalString`?

Comment: Basically, when you pass an `Object` to print, like this: `System.out.println(Object)`, it really just does `System.out.println(Object.toString())`

Comment: @user2357112, I was not aware what method is being called and why/how, and hence this question. And Thank you Zizouz212

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using an ide like eclipse, you might have noticed a mark near your method toString() that says `overrides java.lang.Object.toString`. This is the method that is being called by default when you are trying to print an object. This looks like

```
 * @return  a string representation of the object.
 */
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Since you have your own definitions inside the method by the same name, it is getting overridden. You can notice the difference if you rename your own `toString` method to something else, and the output would be something like `Time1@2a139a55`

Comment: Well, I didn't notice that. Clicking on it opens that other class, and makes sense on why my own custom class is giving `AM/PM` whereas the default one is giving kind of a memory location.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is in your `toString` method. What the following does

```
((hour==0 || hour==12)?12:hour%12)
```

is, whenever the value of hour is either `0` or `12`, print 12, otherwise print `hour % 12`.

When you call:

```
System.out.println(thistime);
```

the print result will be the same as:

```
System.out.println(thistime.toString());
```

so this is why the `toString` method is invoked. You can write something like `((hour == 12) ? 12 : hour % 12)` to fix it.

Comment: It's not converted. `PrintStream.println()` is overloaded for `Object`, where `String.valueOf()` is called.

Answer (score 6):

When you call `System.out.println(thistime);` for your object, your `toString` method is executed, and the String it returns is printed.

Your `toString` method explicitly returns 12 when `hours == 0` :

```
return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s", ((hour==0 || hour==12)?12:hour%12),minute, second, (hour<12?"AM":"PM"));

                                          -------
```

Comment: Thank you Eran, but I didn't call this method, so why was this method applied?

Comment: @scott When you attempt to print an object it calls `toString`.

Comment: Thank you. Answers my question. :)

Answer (score 4):

System.out.println expects a String as parameter, so it calls your toString Method to convert your Time1 Object into a String. Due to the logic you have in there, you are seeing the "12:00:00 AM" output.

You can do

```
System.out.println(time1.toUniversalString());
```

to get the output you expect;

Answer (score 4):

> I was expecting System.out.println(thistime); before using the
>   setTime() method to return 00:00:00 because I haven't used any methods
>   to reformat it, however I am getting the output as 12:00:00 AM, that
>   is equal to calling toString() method. Why was this method being
>   called by default when a new object is initialized, even without being
>   called for?

When you print object(which you did with `System.out.println(thistime)`), its `toString` method is called(even without explicit calling) by default. Its as simple as that.

Comment: This is wrong. `PrintStream.println()` is overloaded for `Object`, where `String.valueOf()` is explicitly called.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` method is overloaded and calls `.toString()` for anything that is not primitive. The print method can format primitive values but calls `toString()` for any `Object` subclass.